# Spark-SQl DataFrame partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-partitioning

I need to load an Hive table using spark-sql and then to run some machine-learning algho on that. I do that writing:

```
val dataSet = sqlContext.sql(" select * from table")
```

It works well, but If I wanted to increase number of partions of the dataSet Dataframe, How can I could do that?
With normal RDD I can do writing:

```
val dataSet = sc.textFile(" .... ", N )
```

With N number of partitions I want to have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `coalesce` or `repartition` the resulting `DataFrame`, i.e.:

```
val dataSet = sqlContext.sql(" select * from table").coalesce(N)
```

Comment: It is pretty expensive operation, right?
The coalesce overhead should anyway be reduced by speeding up training step.
Thanks

Comment: Yes,it is. It involves transferring all the data among the nodes of the cluster. Another option may be trying to set the `spark.default.parallelism` configuration property, but you have to try, I don't know if it works...

Comment: You can also check this link  https://deepsense.io/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/